# What is a "Toggle Transcript"?

Tags: ftp, cyberduck

I'm having trouble downloading files from my client's development server.
They said that one of their connections is working just fine with the exact same FTP credentials.

To help resolve the problem they asked me to give them "Toggle Transcripts"

What are toggle transcripts and how can I get them from CyberDuck?

Answer (score 1):

In my version, I have a "Toggle Log Drawer" menu option (under the View menu, I think). Selecting this reveals an extra window element, where information about the FTP session is printed. In your case, this window may contain information that your client can use to diagnose the problem. It's just a log of your activity when using Cyberduck.